# Outlook VBA Out of Office - Setting a Date + Formatting

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

im using Outlook 2013 and need help activating Out Of Office with VBA. I have trouble setting a starting and endtime as well as formatting my message. I seem not to be able to use html tags... 
Is there also a way of getting my current signature?

The code so far:

```
Sub absence(toggle As Boolean)

Const PR_OOF_STATE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B"

Dim oStore As Outlook.Store, oProp As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim oStorageItem As Outlook.StorageItem

Set oStorageItem = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).GetStorage("IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft", olIdentifyByMessageClass)

oStorageItem.Body = "<html><body><b>I am curerntly not available...</b></body></html>"

oStorageItem.Save


For Each oStore In Session.Stores
    If oStore.ExchangeStoreType = olPrimaryExchangeMailbox Then

        Set oProp = oStore.PropertyAccessor
        oProp.SetProperty PR_OOF_STATE, toggle 'If true: start OOF, if false: quit OOF

    End If
Next
Set olkIS = Nothing
Set olkPA = Nothing

End Sub
```

Anyone got an idea? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is not working? What are the error codes?

Comment: the current code works fine, but i would like to activate the Out of Office only between a specific Date. Additionally i would like to format the Body...

Comment: Seems to me that you do not google but want a bugfree tested code in return. I did google and found an answer to your question. This is not a free programming service. You need to take actions yourself to solve what you are after.

Comment: could you tell me where you found it? I have spent hours looking, but didnt find anything useful.

Comment: I just used your keywords.Google is superior

Comment: For most problems, regardless of topic, it all boils down to ask correctly (on Google). And, yes, it is a skill. Learn it. Earn it!

Comment: wow.. thank you for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

HTML OOF replies and time ranges can only be set using EWS - see SetUserOofSettings operation on MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/setuseroofsettings-operation)