# How to set a recurring Out of Office for same time every week?

Tags: vba, outlook

I do not work from 12 to 5 on Fridays. I need to set an automatic recurring Out of Office reply for this time. I use Office 365.

I searched and cannot get any examples I tried to work.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Dim objMAPISession As Object
    Set objReminders = Nothing
    If MsgBox(“Would you like to turn the Out of Office Assistant on?”, vbYesNo, “Activate Out of Office Assistant”) = vbYes Then
        Set objMAPISession = CreateObject(“MAPI.Session”)
        objMAPISession.Logon , , True, False
        objMAPISession.OutOfOffice = True
        objMAPISession.Logoff
    End If
    Set objMAPISession = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error message?  As it stands, your `If` statement won't work - it either needs to all be one line (`If MsgBox(“Would you like to turn the Out of Office Assistant on?”, vbYesNo, “Activate Out of Office Assistant”) = vbYes Then`), or have a continuation character (`_`) after the `,`.  Also, your code does not include any date/time checks, which might be a good place to start.

Comment: Also - as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703402/outlook-vba-out-of-office-setting-a-date-formatting) question, you may want to check whether the actions you are trying to undertake require access to Exchange Web Service

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting a syntax error with this line:                                             
If MsgBox(“Would you like to turn the Out of Office Assistant on?”, vbYesNo, “Activate Out of Office Assistant”) = vbYes Then                                                                  How do I fix it?

Comment: Ah, just noticed that you've had the proper double-quotes (`"`) replaced with curly ones (`“ and ”`) - correct them to the straight ones from your keyboard, and it should fix that issue

Comment: Thanks that fixed that issue. I'm now getting the error: Run-time error '424': Object Required

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Office time range can only be set using EWS. Older versions of Exchange (that is what CD 1.21 was designed for) can only set OOF on or off; time range was not supported.

But even in the latest versions of Exchange, OOF cannot be scheduled as a recurring pattern, you'd have to do that manually.

Comment: Can I fix the code above so that it sets up a button to turn it on when I quit outlook so at least it prompts me to put it on when I leave?

Comment: It's what it is meant to do, but I get a Run-time error 424 - object required and I'm unsure why?

Comment: Are you sure CDO 1.21 is installed? You can download it manually as Outlook no longer installs it.

Comment: @MattD Do you know **which line** you get the error message on?